# R data.table Performing a by aggregation on a joined column

Tags: r, join, data.table

I want to do an aggregation on the result of a join (x and i are keyed data.tables) without materializing the whole result. It is similar to what .EACHI tries to resolve but for columns that are added by the join.

```
D1 <- data.table(x = rnorm(1:100), i = sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE), k = sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE))
D2 <- data.table(x = rnorm(1:100), j = sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE), k = sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE))
setkey(D1, k)
setkey(D2, k)
```

I would like to sum x on the result of the join of D1 and D2 for the pairs i and j without materializing the result of D1[D2]

```
D1[D2, list(x = sum(x * i.x)), by = list(i, j), allow.cartesian = TRUE] ## Fails
D1[D2, allow.cartesian = TRUE][, list(x = sum(x * i.x)), by = list(i, j)] ## Is the result I want but uses up more memory
```

Is there a way to do this? If not will it be implemented in a future version?

Comment: It's planned, but I guess it's not easy https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733

Comment: Thanks @Frank I guess it makes it a duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974145/r-data-table-group-by-attribute-of-i-table?noredirect=1#comment61505368_36974145

Comment: Good point. We can't close it as a dupe until that question has an accepted answer, though. I've left a comment on the github issue to update this post after the feature's in.

Comment: @Frank, the issue you linked is only part of the problem. I don't think it makes sense to group by `D2`'s columns (here, `i`) within `D1[...]`, and that's not part of #733.

Comment: @Arun My bad I got the indices mixed up. I meant D1[D2, list(x = sum(x * i.x)), by = list(i, j)] in which case we fall into the same case described by the other SO question

Comment: My point was about your use of column `i` (which is from `D2`) in `by`, which normally corresponds to grouping variables from `D1` (except for `.EACHI` case).

Comment: @Arun I realized I made some other mistakes in my example. To summarize D1 has three columns (i, k, x) and D2 also (j, k, x). Join is done on column k and aggregation is done on i, which belong to D1 and j, which belongs to D2. This is the same feature request as in the other SO question and the github thread. I see it as a generalization of the .EACHI feature. The problem is not so much that it's not possible to do this computation but that the memory usage is far from optimal. Sorry again for the mixup, I hope it's clearer now. Thanks a lot for looking into this :)

Comment: Are you using columns from `D2` in `by` or not?

Comment: @Arun yes column j is from D2

Comment: Then my comment still holds. I'm not sure what it has to do with the mistakes you've fixed. I don't think `D1[..., by=]` makes sense with grouping using columns from `D2`. `by=` refers to grouping by columns in `D1`.

Comment: @Arun You're right my problem is a bit more complex. There is a column from 'i' in the 'j' argument and a  column from 'i' in the 'by' argument, whereas in the other question there's no column from 'i' in the 'by' argument. I was hoping for something that extends .EACHI, something that performs the aggregation specified in 'j' without materializing the whole join. Maybe it's not possible to implement it with data.table's design. My understanding of how things work with data.table is quite shallow to be honest.