# Is it possible to subset by data.table X[Y] and group by variable from Y in a single data.table expression?

Tags: r, data.table

When I subset by data.table and group by variable from it in one expression I get the following error:

```
> dt1 = data.table(a = 1:2, b1 = 1, key = "a")
> dt2 = data.table(a = 1:2, b2 = 1, key = "a")
> dt1[dt2, .N, by = c("b1", "b2")]
Error in eval(bysub, xss, parent.frame()) : object 'b2' not found
```

It works when I group by variable from dt1 only:

```
> dt1[dt2, .N, by = "b1"]
   b1 N
1:  1 2
```

And it works if I divide it into two consecutive expressions:

```
> dt1[dt2][, .N, by = c("b1", "b2")]
   b1 b2 N
1:  1  1 2
```

Can I get it into a single expression anyhow?

Comment: `dt1[dt2]` is not a subset in `data.table` it's a right outer join. `.N, by = c("b1", "b2")]` is conflicting with the join syntax, hence why you have to do one operation first, then the other.

Comment: @Mako212 I know it really means right join but the syntax is reading as subsetting. So it's just a terminology. It 's not getting clear from your answer why this particular syntax with columns from the right-sight table conflicts with the join. I've added an example with grouping by left-side variables only. And it works.

Comment: I've managed to find the same questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465117/r-data-table-performing-a-by-aggregation-on-a-joined-column
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974145/r-data-table-group-by-attribute-of-i-table
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824705/using-on-and-by-to-compute-a-new-variable-from-two-data-tables
None of them is answered so I can't close this as a dupe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is caused by the fact you have an object of class `data.table` within your brackets `[ ]`. As soon as that condition is met, the behavior of arguments within the brackets changes to facilitate the join. Given that you're not the only one that has had this issue, as your links illustrate, I think chaining the two statements is the best way to do it.

Comment: Although i dont understand why it must be within a single square bracket, are u looking for `dt1[dt2, .SD[, .N, by=.(b1, b2)]]` ???

Comment: @chinsoon12 I'm seeking a way to deal with multi-gigabyte tables and a cartesian join that leads to more than 2^31 rows before grouping and hence impossible as an intermediate stage. So it would be a good solution if data.table could make joining and grouping in a single pass possibly including some internal optimisations. Your proposal is extremely slow on such a big tables and fails on cartesian join anyway :(